# ERROR in The loader ".../src/app/app.component.html" didn't return a string

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have been working on a nativescript 6 application with angular 9, they asked me to update the app to nativescript 7 with angular 11, I had some problems and right now I am, with this.

ERROR in The loader "C:/App/src/app/app.component.html" didn't return a string.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX1Mt.png)

I use the following documentation for upgrade nativescript version:

https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-7-announcement/

my package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "10.0.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "7.0.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.3.3",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "3.0.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-cardview": "^1.0.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-checkbox": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-akylas-themes": "^2.0.2",
    "nativescript-appversion": "^1.4.4",
    "nativescript-camera": "^4.5.0",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "^5.0.6",
    "nativescript-feedback": "^1.3.12",
    "nativescript-google-maps-sdk": "^2.9.1",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^7.1.0",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.5.2",
    "nativescript-ui-calendar": "^6.1.0",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^8.2.0",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "~8.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.1",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "^1.0.0",
    "@nativescript/types": "7.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~8.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.1",
    "tns-android": "6.5.3",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.5"
  },
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "main": "main.js"
}
```

I am aware that I have not updated some angular dependencies but in another branch I did the update and the error continued.

Comment: I got the same error.

Comment: @KaushikMakwana I fixed it using this content inside my webpack

https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/204b5a427b11a411ffd70468155e149bda168755/packages/webpack/templates/webpack.angular.js

Comment: what changes we need to do?

Comment: I guess there's still no clear solution.